# Generators of group of "unitary" matrices over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

This is about a group related to $U(n,q)$ and $SU(n,q)$. I know from multiple sources the generators for these groups, but $U(n,q)$ is defined to be the group of matrices $A$ such that $A^*JA = J$ where $A^*$ means the conjugate transpose of $A$, and $J$ is the identity on the secondary diagonal. And with conjugate I mean the frobenius over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$. At least this is the definition I encountered when using packages like Sage, Magma, Gap, etc.

What I am specifically searching for are the generators for the group of matrices $A \in SL(3,\mathbb{F}_9)$ such that $A^*A = I$. Or maybe a transformation that sends matrices in $SU(3,3)$ to matrices of this kind.

Comment: Well if you are familiar with GAP, Magma, etc, then you can define the groups there, and see what their generators are.

Comment: I am familiar with those packages, and I have looked into the manuals/sources to find a way to do it without taking a brute force approach, which I also tried, but i haven't found a succesful way to get it right as of yet.